# Mysql order by multiple columns with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have application using Mysql Database with this schema for example.

```
packages
id, name,       order
1, 'Free',      3
2, 'Basic',     2
3, 'Extensive', 1

ads
id,    date,                    package_id,   package_expires_at
1,     '2021-12-10 00:00:00',   1,            '2022-01-10'
2,     '2021-12-15 00:00:00',   3,            '2021-12-28'
3,     '2021-12-15 00:00:00',   3,            '2022-01-10'
4,     '2021-12-20 00:00:00',   2,            '2022-01-10'
5,     '2021-12-21 00:00:00',   1,            '2021-12-28'
6,     '2021-12-25 00:00:00',   1,            '2021-12-28'
```

What I need to achieve is selecting all ads but ordering none expired package first `by packages.order asc, package_expire_at desc` then order the expired by `date desc`

for example suppose we are in '2021-12-29' then the result should be

```
id,    date,                    package_id,   package_expires_at
3,     '2021-12-15 00:00:00',   3,            '2022-01-10'
4,     '2021-12-20 00:00:00',   2,            '2022-01-10'
1,     '2021-12-10 00:00:00',   1,            '2022-01-10'
6,     '2021-12-25 00:00:00',   1,            '2021-12-28'
5,     '2021-12-21 00:00:00',   1,            '2021-12-28'
2,     '2021-12-15 00:00:00',   3,            '2021-12-28'
```

I have added the schema on fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cedb45/9

Comment: are the dates stored as DATE or DATETIME fields ?

Comment: ```date``` is datetime fields, but package_expires_at is ```date``` fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do this in (My)SQL is, you provide a virtual field as `ORDER BY` condition.
Something like this should probably do the trick:

```
      SELECT a.id
           , a.date
           , a.package_id
           , a.package_expires_at
           , IF( a.package_expires_at < CURRENT_DATE,  1,         0                      ) AS is_expired
           , IF( a.package_expires_at < CURRENT_DATE,  a.`date`,  a.`package_expires_at` ) AS sort_date
           , p.`order`                                                                     AS sort_package_order
        FROM ads       AS  a
  INNER JOIN packages  AS  p 
          ON p.id = a.package_id
    ORDER BY IF( a.package_expires_at < CURRENT_DATE,  1,         0                      ) ASC
           , IF( a.package_expires_at < CURRENT_DATE,  1,         p.`order`              ) ASC
           , IF( a.package_expires_at < CURRENT_DATE,  a.`date`,  a.`package_expires_at` ) DESC
```

Comment: I added a fiddle link you can test on it

Comment: good job; but it should work already right?

Comment: unfortunately not the expected result

Comment: Whats different? It follows the `order asc, then package_expire_at desc` order for active items, and then `date desc` order for expired items as you asked for.

Comment: look at my expected result it should return 3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 2 but result in fiddle returned 3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 2

Comment: The dates in the fiddle and your those in your example here are different, so different order is to be expected. Also all 6 in your example here are all un-expired, which isn't the case in your fiddle. The results match up to your criteria though: id2 is on the bottom as its the only expired one; id#3 has order=1 so it comes first, then id#4 because it has order=2; the remaining 3 are all non-expired and also all order=3 so they order on expirydate which is #5 & #6 first (theyre equal) and then #1 as it has a lower date.

Comment: Alright, I have written some mistakes so thats why it wasn't the same as yours, sorry for that and it seems like your query worked as expected, thanks alot

Comment: No worries; you can add some extra (virtual) columns as well, to make it easier to get a feel for whats going on; i'll add 3 columns in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use two separate query and then `union` them (your packages order is upside down of its ids now)

```
select * from (SELECT * from ads WHERE package_expires_at >= '2021-12-29' order by package_id asc, package_expires_at desc ) as a
union
select * from (SELECT * from ads WHERE package_expires_at < '2021-12-29' order by date desc) as b
```

if they are dynamic and without order, join them and then do things such as above .

```
select * from (SELECT ads.id,date,package_id,package_expires_at from ads left outer join packages on package_id = ads.id WHERE package_expires_at >= '2021-12-29' order by packages.order asc, package_expires_at desc ) as a
union
select * from ( SELECT ads.id,date,package_id,package_expires_at from ads left outer join packages on package_id = ads.id WHERE package_expires_at < '2021-12-29' order by date desc ) as b
```

Comment: This is not gonna work because I use pagination in Laravel and its gonna cause some problems.